# Need some change on this regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Im checking some strings with my regex and somehow its not perfect. Im not sure why. I would like to allow string with only these characters:

- A to Z
- 0 to 9
- .
- %
- /
- {space}
- +
- $

So I thought this regex should be enough:

```
Regex("[^A-Z0-9.$/+%\\- ]$")
```

But with some string its not really working. I made a small example:

```
    static Regex regex = new Regex("[^A-Z0-9.$/+%\\- ]$");

    static void Main()
    {
        string s;

        Console.WriteLine("check: \n");

        s = "?~=) 2313";
        Console.WriteLine(s + ": " +IsValid(s));

        s = "ÄÜÖ";
        Console.WriteLine(s + ": " + IsValid(s));

        s = "Ü~=) 2313";
        Console.WriteLine(s + ": " + IsValid(s));

        s = "Ü 2313";
        Console.WriteLine(s + ": " + IsValid(s));

        s = "~=) 2313 Ü";
        Console.WriteLine(s + ": " + IsValid(s));

        s = "ÜÜÜ";
        Console.WriteLine(s + ": " + IsValid(s));

        s = "~=)";
        Console.WriteLine(s + ": " + IsValid(s));

        s = "THIS--STRING $1234567890$ SHOULD BE VALID.%/ +";
        Console.WriteLine(s + ": " + IsValid(s));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static bool IsValid(string input)
    {
        if (regex.IsMatch(input)) return false;
        return true;
    }
```

As output I get:

[image]

The 1.,3. and 4. are True, but this is wrong. What is wrong with my regex? Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
^[A-Z0-9.$/+%\\- ]+$
|                 ||match end of the string
|                 |
|                 |match one or more characters of [A-Z0-9.$/+%\\- ]
|start of the string
```

You need to use quantifiers like `+`,`*` to match multiple characters

---

Your **IsValid** Class should be

```
public static bool IsValid(string input)
    {
        if (regex.IsMatch(input)) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: `I would like to allow string with only these characters`. Your character class is inverted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex (Did you mean to include `-` in your description of allowed characters?):

```
Regex("^[A-Z0-9.$/+% -]*$")
```

Comment: Wouldn't that need another backslash?

Comment: Why would it? It's meant to escape the hyphen. Edit: I moved it to the end of the character class instead so it wouldn't be confusing.

Comment: The first backslash escapes the second.

Comment: Yes; the backslash is intended for the regex, but since it's inside a string, we have to escape the backslash itself first so it reaches the regex parser.

Comment: With this if IsValid() is false, then the string is correct :) How to negate this?

Comment: @sabisabi, Well, simply negating the character class wouldn't do it, because then you would still get matches that have only some characters in the class. The easiest way without rethinking the whole regex would probably be to just negate the result you get from IsValid(). Asad mentions this in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is matching only one character that is not any of those characters. Your regex should be:

```
^[A-Z0-9\.$/+% ]+$
```

Also, use a non-inverted function for your check:

```
public static bool IsValid(string input)
{
    if (regex.IsMatch(input)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: his `isValid` class is **inverted**..this regex would give opposite result

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It Yes, but this seems somewhat unnecessary. I'll edit in the fix.

Comment: OP seems to want hyphens in their character class; see their first regex attempt and their last string which they say should pass.